# Sea breeze - magnitude of horizontal pressure gradient?

Tags: meteorology, wind, scaling

What is the range of horizontal pressure gradients typically caused by the differential heating of land and water under sea breeze conditions?

Comment: In my notes I have this modeled as a density current on at a constant pressure.  When I get some free time I'll look deeper at it.  Perhaps even model it.

Comment: @aretxabaleta's answer is a good start, but it indicates that the question could have some more detail: Are you interested in the extreme ranges, or just common behaviours? And for just a single site, or for any place/terrain type on earth?

Answer (score 8):

In his book, Simpson (Simpson, J. E. (1994). Sea breeze and local winds. Cambridge University Press) shows a figure that includes the pressure difference between Jersey in the Channel Islands and Paris. It gives an idea of the magnitude of the pressure difference. As was mentioned in the comments, sea breeze tends to be perceived as a density current on constant pressure surfaces.

[image]